# Reactjs onFocus event doesn't work with keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I encountered a problem: my form has inputs and I need to do some action when those inputs focused.

Here is my code: `<Input onFocus={console.error("focus" + index)}/>`
With mouse it works correctly, but when I focused on input with keyboard it doesn't work.

Please, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is executed at the loading time, you need to wrap it into function, i.e.:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
   <input onFocus={(index) => console.log("focus" + index)} />,
 document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: If it is working for you then please, accept as correct one